# SQL Merge Replication

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is SQL merge replication possible in Windows Phone 8?

Are there any resources on this topic, my google-fu is letting me down.

Comment: This being posted a few years ago gives me hope that you found a solution/workaround. Any luck? I'm looking for a similar solutions.

Comment: I'm afraid not - the project didn't go ahead./

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no. The repl libraries aren't available on Windows Phone 7 or 8.

Comment: Thanks Rob and welcome to StackOverflow.  That's a real shame.  I have an app coded for WM6 which uses merge replication which I want to rewrite for WP8, do you know what options I have to replace the missing functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This article on dzone from February suggests that it is meant to be possible:

> The latest release ... of (SQL Server Compact) version 3.5 SP2 is fully supported
>   for Merge Replication with SQL Server 2012 ...
>   On Windows Phone, version 3.5 is alive and well, and will of course
>   also be included with the upcoming Windows Phone 8 platform.

http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/sql-server-ce-database

In terms of general resources, the SQL Server Compact MVP who wrote the article above has a blog that might be of interest:

- [Everything SQL Server Compact](http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/)

Comment: I did already find this link.  I have VS2012 and the Windows Phone 8 SDK installed.  I have the option to add SQL Server Compact 4.0 databases to a Windows Phone 8 project but not SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2.  The only downloads I can find for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 are for Windows Mobile or Windows Desktop.  SQL Server Compact 4.0 does not support any kind of merge replication.